# Storing file folder path from dropzonejs with readAsDataURL

Tags: javascript, php, path, directory

Was trying Dropzone.js for image uploadeder with PHP as described in https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php. But wanted to store all the folder paths that the image has locally in the $targetFile name. So tried to combine this with javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Any suggestions on what to do with this example, would be good. Javascript has error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

```js
Dropzone.options.my-dropzone = {

   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   maxFilesize: 50, // MB
   acceptedFiles: "image/jpg, image/jpeg", 
   params: { relativePath : reader },
   init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
            console.log(responseText);
        });
    }
};
```

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$storeFolder = 'Images';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];           

$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

$targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']. "_". $_FILES['file']['relativePath'];

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

}

Comment: i think you can only do that in webkit, using folder entries, otherwise the path is redacted.

Comment: that's to bad, but would you happen to see what mistake I have done in the dropzone javascript? Would me nice to just have any way.